# Where can I look up the NFT metadata?

Tags: solana

If you go to https://explorer.solana.com/address/BD2i6K4EZ3upo4RNvT8xgzGApte5mpRCLDaMv5S8Vh6Y/metadata you can see SOME of the NFT metadata but not all. Where can I look up the [attributes](http://docs.metaplex.com/nft-standard) (trait_type: trait_value)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this tool to get metadata from an NFT that was generated with the metaplex standard

https://www.vicyyn.com/#/nft